# Is there a way to increase precision on a JavaFX chart's tick marks?

Tags: javafx

I found a problem with the decimal precision on JavaFX chart tick mark labels when changing autoranging on a chart's axis to false. Here's a quick example:

```
package chart;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Chart extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        yAxis.setUpperBound(1);
        yAxis.setLowerBound(.999);
        yAxis.setTickUnit(.0001);
        ScatterChart<Number, Number> chart = new ScatterChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<>());
        Scene scene = new Scene(chart, 600, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        chart.getData().get(0).getData().add(new Data(1, .9999));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If the autoranging is turned to true, the tick mark labels on the Y axis go to 4 decimal places while it only goes to 3 places when it is false. It also does some sort of rounding to the tick labels. How can I get the same precision on the autoranging without it being turned on?

Comment: This site encourages people to show what they've already tried, or the research they've already done. As a general point, looking up the documentation is usually _much_ faster than waiting for someone to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `tickUnit` property of the `NumberAxis` is set automatically when `autoRanging` is true. So by setting auto ranging, you're telling the axis to ignore your custom tick unit. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#setTickUnit-double-).